# Tomcat hangs if C3P0 can't get a database connection

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, c3p0

I've an application that uses Spring+Hibernate+C3P0 as the connection pool. If I start the application and the database is down, Tomcat hangs for a long log time withouth giving any feedback. Is there some property that I can set to avoid this? For example, if after 30 seconds it can't get a connection, throw a connection timeout exception.

Answer (score 2):

By default, it should take about 30 seconds before c3p0 signals a failure if it cannot acquire a Connection. You can control the length of time by modifying either the number of attempts c3p0 makes at the database or the interval between attempts.

See [c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryAttempts) and [c3p0.acquireRetryDelay](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#acquireRetryDelay).

If you set c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts to one, c3p0 won't retry and connection attempts will fail retry immediately.

See also [Configuring Recovery From Database Outages](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_recovery).